# Need to Create this HTML/CSS Grid Layout

Tags: html, css, web, css-float, css-position

I need my page to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niaTx.png) but, despite my efforts, I have not been able to get anything to work.

Here is what I currently have:

```
.1 {
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 50%;
```

}

```
.2 {
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 50%;
```

}

```
.3 {
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 50%;
```

}

[Here is what it ends up looking like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBM6N.png)

Comment: Use floats instead of absolute position. 1 - float right, 2 & 3 float left or don't float. Also set a height.

Comment: Thank you, but the heights of the divs need to be set dynamically.

Comment: Then don't set the heights, let the inner content take care of it. Even if you're settings heights dynamically, floats work just fine for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a layout like that using CSS Grid layout

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layout{
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 100px 500px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "m d1 d3"
    "m d2 d3"
    "m . d3"
    "m d4 d4";
}


.menu{
    grid-area: m;
    background: rgb(46, 139, 87);

}

.div1{
    grid-area: d1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.div2{
    grid-area: d2;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.div3{
    grid-area: d3;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.div4{
    grid-gap: 0px;
    grid-area: d4;
    background: rgb(245, 95, 68);
}
```

```html
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="menu">Menu</div>
        <div class="div1">div_1</div>
        <div class="div2">div_2</div>
        <div class="div3">div_3</div>

        <div class="div4">div_4</div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by **Bootstrap** row and col as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Arnold Parge</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .my_box {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my_box"></div>
            <div class="my_box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my_box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my_box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would prefer not to use Bootstrap.